# Blur parts of image monogame pixelshader

Tags: c#, monogame, hlsl

So I've managed to come up with a shader that will block parts of an image based on positions of certain line segments (to summarize the pixel shader, it simply checks if the line segment from the center of the light to any given pixel intersects any of the 'wall' line segments and thus doesn't draw the image if so).

However, my issue here is the the cutoff of the light is very sharp, and I'd like to blur it a bit, without blurring the hard edge where the light meets the wall segment.  What would be a good way to accomplish this?  I've attached a gif of the shader in action and the relevant code.

[Light Shader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEGmM.gif)

[Stuff circled in red should be blurry, green should remain sharp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03bNR.png)

```
float4 MainPS(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR
{
    float4 color = tex2D(s0, input.TextureCoordinates);
    float2 centerPos = float2(150.0f + mX, 150.0f + mY);
    float2 coords = float2((input.TextureCoordinates.x * 300) + mX, (input.TextureCoordinates.y * 300) + mY);

    //change alpha based on distance
    color.w = map(distance(centerPos, coords), 0, 150, .5, .1f);
    //If the line segment from the center to this pixel intersects any given line segment (hardcoded for now, don't draw it)
    if (intersect(centerPos, coords, float2(160.0f, 200.0f), float2(200.0f, 140.0f)) || 
    intersect(centerPos, coords, float2(160.0f, 200.0f), float2(250.0f, 200.0f)) || intersect(centerPos, coords, float2(200.0f, 140.0f), float2(250.0f, 200.0f)))
        color = float4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return color;
}
```

Any help/tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to computing whether the line from the center to the current pixel intersects the line segment, you can compute the exact position of the intersection, and then use the distance between the intersection point and the current pixel to soften the shadow, with something along the lines of:

```
float2 intersectionPos;
if (intersect(centerPos, coords, float2(160.0f, 200.0f), float2(200.0f, 140.0f), intersectionPos) ||
    intersect(centerPos, coords, float2(160.0f, 200.0f), float2(250.0f, 200.0f), intersectionPos) || 
    intersect(centerPos, coords, float2(200.0f, 140.0f), float2(250.0f, 200.0f), intersectionPos)) 
{
    color.w *= lerp(1, 0, saturate(distance(coords, intersectionPos) / BLUR_DISTANCE))
}
```

Where `BLUR_DISTANCE` is some small number that indicates how far from the line segment to blur pixels and `intersect` is defined as:

```
bool intersect(float2 origin, float2 point, float2 segEnd1, float2 segEnd2, inout float2 intersectionPos) {
    // implement this to set intersectionPos *only* if there's actually an intersection
}
```

For prettier results, you might use a nonlinear interpolation function, or compute the distance to the closest point on the line rather than the ray intersection, but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just noticed a separate issue when trying to use multiple lights with the same shader- the line segments appear to move?  I think it has something to do with how I set the parameter of the light before I draw it?

Comment: _spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.Additive);
            lightEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
            lightEffect.Parameters["mX"].SetValue(pos.X);
            lightEffect.Parameters["mY"].SetValue(pos.Y);
            _spriteBatch.Draw(lightTexture, pos, Color.White);
            lightEffect.Parameters["mX"].SetValue(pos.X + 50);
            lightEffect.Parameters["mY"].SetValue(pos.Y + 50);
            _spriteBatch.Draw(lightTexture, pos + new Vector2(50, 50), Color.White);
            _spriteBatch.End();

Comment: figured it out, it had something to do with the order of the calls?  What is the proper procedure regarding settiing parameter values and applying technique passes?

Comment: @AdrianWheeler While I know HLSL, I don't have any knowledge of the particulars of MonoGame. If you run into it again, you can ask another question and someone more qualified will be able to help.